# Strange behaviour with Gimp and Wacom

Tags: input-devices, wacom, graphics-tablet, gimp

When I enable the wacom tablet in the Gimp extended input devices (setting it to 'screen'), to use the pressure sensitivity, it starts to behave strangely. I cannot pick guides from the rulers and the selection tool (the marching ants) become invisible. Has anyone had the same problem? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 3):

Do you always have this problem? It happens randomly here - sometimes I can use GIMP for hours without the problem. Anyways, it is a known bug and unfortunately there seems to be no workaround.

See [Bugzilla bug 595678](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=595678) or the duplicate [Bugzilla bug 607856](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=607856).

Comment: I'm not going back to windows. I hope they solve it on the next version of gimp...